# Visual Studio 2010 MVC 4 - Can't re-use project name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I use a name for a project then delete it, attempting to use the same name for a future project fails with the error "The process cannot access the file \\packages.config because it is being used by another process."

This occurs even after I've deleted all the project files, and deleted the project from the Projects folder and deleted the project backup file (which, when I did a search on the project name, I discovered VS creates). In other words I've deleted all references to the project name that I can find. So obviously there must be a record somewhere that is pretty well hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Reboot after deleting everything?  Might have a process in the background accessing the file.

Comment: Reboot worked for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the packages folder that is usually created in the same directory as the sln file?
I recently did this, and that was the one I missed.